# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] and URLError when using urllib in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout, urllib

I am trying to read and parse website content. I am using Python 3.5.2 But I have done it for like 300.000 entries. At some point, I got two errors;

```
    1.TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
    2. AttributeError: type object 'URLError' has no attribute 'reason'
```

I have searched for these errors and tried some of the solutions. But, I am still getting them. I dont know how to solve the first error. For the second errors, it tells me there is no attribute "reason" in URLError. But I have also tried "code" attribute. In addition to this, the webpage exist when I control it, why I am getting these errors. How can I solve two of the errors?

```
    Error in pdb no chain added. Obj is empty. 3dzd
    <class 'urllib.error.URLError'>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1254, in do_open
        h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1106, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 934, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 877, in send
        self.connect()
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in connect
        super().connect()
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 849, in connect
        (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Bağlanılan uygun olarak belli bir süre içinde yanıt vermediğinden veya kurulan

    bağlantı bağlanılan ana bilgisayar yanıt vermediğinden bir bağlantı kurulamadı

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\...\Google Drive\Scripts\4\script_4.py", line 146, in read_url_content
        data = list(urlopen("https://files.rcsb.org/view/"+pdb+".pdb", context = context ,timeout=60)) # it's a file like object and works just like a file
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 466, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 484, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1297, in https_open
        context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
      File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1256, in do_open
        raise URLError(err)
    urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] Bağlanılan uygun olarak belli bir süre içinde yanıt vermediğinden veya kurulan

    bağlantı bağlanılan ana bilgisayar yanıt vermediğinden bir bağlantı kurulamadı>

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\...\Google Drive\Scripts\4\script_4.py", line 207, in <module>
        obj = read_url_content(pdb)
      File "C:\...\Google Drive\Scripts\4\script_4.py", line 156, in read_url_content
        print(e.reason)
    AttributeError: type object 'URLError' has no attribute 'reason'
```

My code is like following;

```
    import requests
    import time
    from urllib.request import urlopen  # the lib that handles the url stuff
    import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
    import ssl
    import sys
    from socket import timeout
    def read_url_content(pdb):
        pdbObj = None
        try:
            context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
            data = list(urlopen("https://files.rcsb.org/view/"+pdb+".pdb", context = context ,timeout=60)) # it's a file like object and works just like a file
            pdbObj = PDB(pdb)
        except urllib.error.URLError as e:
            print("Error in pdb no chain added. Obj is empty.", pdb)
            ResponseData = e.reason
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print(e)
            print(e.reason)
            pass
        except timeout:
            logging.error('socket timed out - URL %s', pdb)
        return pdbObj
```

Comment: Probably you exceeded some sort of request limit, and the server is temporarily irresponsive. That would be 1st exception, then the 2nd one is because `ResponseData = e.reason` (the message is pretty clear). Use `print(dir(e))` to display its fields/methods.

Comment: Thank you. I search for the python documentation "reason" attribute still stay for this error. But I will try it. Additionally, how can I overcome the request limit or irresponsiveness?